# Is there a difference between int[] b = new int[a.length] b=a and int[] b = a?

Tags: java

Is there a difference between

```
int[] b = new int[a.length];
b=a;
```

and

```
int[] b = a;
```

in java?

Comment: If you do `b=a;` after that first statement then the array allocated in the first statement is effectively thrown away.

Comment: is `b=a` the next line of code? Or are you saying that `b` is already equal to `a` before the first line runs?

Comment: Yes, second line, I put all of these commands in a method, does it cause a difference

Comment: @user2864740 can you explain more about it? int[] b = a call new function automatically?

Comment: It's the difference between allocating a new instance of something and pointing to an existing reference of something.

Answer (score 6):

They're mostly the same, but there are a few differences:

- In general, the first one will create an array that immediately becomes unreachable (eligible for garbage collection), so effectively does not exist. (In both versions, `b` ends up referring to the same array as `a`, aside from the caveats below.)
- If `a` is `null`, then the first one will throw a `NullPointerException`.
- If you're unlucky, the first one could throw an `OutOfMemoryError` or similar.
- The first one is much more likely to cause compiler warnings, FindBugs warnings, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that `a` is of type `int[]` and is not null, then ...

In the first snippet, you create a new array, and then throw it away.  In other words,  by reassigning `b` to `a`, the array that you created is inaccessible, and will therefore be garbage collected shortly.

One way in which the two snippets could behave differently is if there is insufficient heap space remaining to create the array, in which case the first snippet will give you an `OutOfMemoryError` and the second will not.  Of course, if `a` is null, then the first snippet will give you a `NullPointerException`.

But normally, if there's enough heap memory, and if `a` is not null, then you'd expect these two snippets to behave identically.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In the first case a new empty array is created of the same length as `a`.

```
int[] b = new int[a.length];
```

You probably then want is a copy of `a` using [`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) so

```
int[] b = new int[a.length];
System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, a.length);
```

In the second case

```
int[] b = a;
```

A new reference to the array `a` is created. That is `b` is only a reference to `a`. A change to either would be reflected in the other.

Comment: I was looking at the other (earlier) answers, and I was really disappointed that no one seemed to have noticed that the OP's code makes it look like he's trying to make a copy of the array `a`. I'm glad you typed this (so that I didn't have to). +1!

Comment: WOW, if you change b it will changes a at the same time...So the first metohd is prefferred right?

Comment: @user3495562 It depends on what (and why) you're doing it.

Comment: @user3495562 In what Elliott has called "the second case", it's not so much that when you change `b`, it changes `a` at the same time.  That's like saying, "WOW, if I send a letter to Samuel Clemens, then Mark Twain receives one as well".  In fact, `a` and `b` end up being two names for the exact same array.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case:

```
int[] b = new int[a.length];
b=a;
```

The array created in the first line will be useless (eligible for garbage collection) when you execute the second line.
This effectively becomes:

```
int[] b = a;
```

`(b == a)` is true in both cases